# click play video with matching element click

Tags: jquery, html, css, video

I'm trying to play HTML5 videos using jQuery. 
I have two videos.

- When I click first video, it works. but, all class title-video hiding.
- When I click second video, video can not play.

this my code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            var video = document.getElementById('video');
            video.addEventListener('click',function(){
                video.play();
                $('#video').attr('controls', true);
                $('.title-video').hide();
            },false);

            video.addEventListener('ended', function(){
                video.load();
                $('#video').attr('controls', false);
                $('.title-video').show();
            })
        })
```

I want only the video that I click.

Any advice would be great.
Thanks

Comment: You are only fetching the video with the `video` id

Comment: do all of your videos have same id?

Comment: @RachelGallen yap, all have same id. Should it be different ? to execute , what methode for i use? Thanks

Comment: @Afrgun you can't have all with same id or you will just have problems. Make a class.

Answer (score 1):

i made this - its just javascript, but it will play the videos in sequence. I put the controls on so that you can skip to the end of a video. (You can also add a size)

Might not be quite what you were after but may give you a start. It uses id, but only because there is only one video container - the src is set in the javascript.

```js
var videoArray = new Array();
videoArray[0] = 'http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4';
videoArray[1] = 'http://www.rachelgallen.com/nature.mp4';
var i = 0; // define i
var videoCount = videoArray.length;

function videoPlay(videoNum) {
  document.getElementById("myVideo").setAttribute("src", videoArray[videoNum]);
  document.getElementById("myVideo").load();
  document.getElementById("myVideo").play();
}
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', playVid, false);
videoPlay(0); // play the video

function playVid() {
  i++;
  if (i == videoCount) {
    i = 0;
    videoPlay(i);
  } else {
    videoPlay(i);
  }
}
```

```html
<video id="myVideo" controls>

</video>
```

Comment: theres a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/4wgpo7m5/1/ with size

Comment: oke. i think i found other solutions click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10019379/pausing-and-playing-multiple-html5-videos-using-jquery-get0-indexing) .

Comment: @Afrgun ah yes, i don't know about the object thing though - that s not html5, you can apply data attributes directly to the video object. google data attributes. The fiddle unfortunately is broken :( thanks for upvote..